# Unable to install WFFM in Sitecore 8.2 update 5

Tags: wffm, mongodb

I have Sitecore 8.2 u5 installed in my PC, with mongodb 3.6.

When I install WFFM 8.2, it keeps running for ever.

The mongodb service wasn't started. When I try to start it from services.msc, it gives an error - Windows cannot start this service.

Could this be a reason.

These are the logs, but they appear even when not installing WFFM.

Exception when executing agent processing/taskAgent
Exception when executing agent aggregation/automationCleanupService

> ERROR Exception when executing agent processing/taskAgent Exception:
>   System.TimeoutException Message: A timeout occured after 30000ms
>   selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
>   WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{
>   AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster
>   state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type :
>   "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId
>   : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }", EndPoint:
>   "Unspecified/localhost:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown",
>   HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An
>   exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:27017    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__27.MoveNext()"
>   }] }. Source: MongoDB.Driver.Core    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector
>   selector, ClusterDescription description)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task
>   completedTask)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector
>   selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask,
>   TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector
>   selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WritableServerBinding.GetWriteChannelSource(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ReadWriteBindingHandle.GetWriteChannelSource(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindAndModifyOperationBase`1.Execute(IWriteBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteOperation`1
>   operation)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.FindAndModify(FindAndModifyArgs args)
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.<>c__DisplayClass2d.b__2c()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.Execute(Action
>   action, ExceptionBehavior exceptionBehavior)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.FindAndModify(IMongoQuery
>   query, IMongoSortBy sortBy, IMongoUpdate update, Boolean returnNew,
>   Boolean upsert)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.MongoDbTaskStorageProvider.PickFirstExclusiveTask()
>   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.TaskQueue.TryGetNext(Guid
>   taskIdBoundary, ProcessingTask& workItem)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.TasksAgent.Execute()    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
>
> 5024 15:54:04 ERROR Exception when executing agent
>   aggregation/automationCleanupService Exception:
>   System.TimeoutException Message: A timeout occured after 30000ms
>   selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
>   WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{
>   AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster
>   state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type :
>   "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId
>   : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }", EndPoint:
>   "Unspecified/localhost:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown",
>   HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An
>   exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:27017    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__27.MoveNext()"
>   }] }. Source: MongoDB.Driver.Core    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector
>   selector, ClusterDescription description)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task
>   completedTask)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector
>   selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask,
>   TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector
>   selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WritableServerBinding.GetReadChannelSource(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ReadWriteBindingHandle.GetReadChannelSource(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.Execute(IReadBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor`1.GetEnumerator()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.RangeScheduler.MongoDbRangeMap2.RemoveFinishedRanges()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.MongoDbAutomationProvider.GetOldestUnaggregatedRangeTimestamp()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.MongoDbAutomationProvider.RemoveAutomationTransitions(DateTime
>   oldestInclusive, DateTime latestExclusive)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Aggregation.Data.Processing.CleanupAgent.Execute()
>   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Sitecore versions that require MongoDB for xDB (7.5 and 8.X), Sitecore requires MongoDB to be running when installing most Sitecore packages. As you experienced, the installation wizard spins forever when MongoDB is not started and the package does not install.

The solution would be to fix your MongoDB installation for it to start and re-install WFFM after.

You should check the MongoDB logs and Windows Event Viewer to find the reason your service is unable to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running CMS-only mode, or do not have Mongo installed (on a development environment for example) then disabling analytics will allow the package to be installed without any errors.

Sitecore 8.1+ natively supports running in [CMS only mode](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/setting%20up%20and%20maintaining/experience%20management/configuring/configure%20experience%20management), set the following setting to **false**:

```
<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="false" />
```

In earlier versions of Sitecore it is the following setting:

```
<setting name="Analytics.Enabled" value="false"/>
```

Note that Sitecore version prior to 8.1 do not natively support running in CMS only mode, but disabling analytics mostly works but not a supported configuration for production.